# I need Help on FTP using Java

Tags: java, ftp, ftplib

i need the source code of an application that can upload and download automatically from the remote computer (FTP) using java language.  thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Apache Commons Net](http://commons.apache.org/net/)

Answer (score 0):

How about [SimpleFTP](http://www.jibble.org/simpleftp/)?

And [here](http://www.example-code.com/java/javaftp.asp) is a nice archive.

Comment: Simple FTP does not support downloads. The second link is not free. That might not be an issue, but it should be specified.

Answer (score 0):

The following site describes four different options for doing FTP client ops in Java.

http://www.nsftools.com/tips/JavaFtp.htm